# Avoiding 'System.OutOfMemoryException' while iterating over a IEnumerable<IEnumerable<object>>

Tags: c#

I have the following code to get the **cheapest** List of objects which satisfy the requiredNumbers criteria. This list of objects can have a length varying from 1 to *maxLength*, i.e. there can be a combination of 1 to *maxLength* of objects with repitition allowed. Right now, this this iterates over the whole list of combinations *(IEnumerable of IEnumerable of OBJECT)* fine till maxLength = 9 and breaks after that with a **"System.OutOfMemoryException"** at

```
 t1.Concat(new OBJECT[] { t2 }
```

I tried another approach to solve this (mentioned in the code comments), but that seems to have its own demons. What I understand right now is , I'll have to somehow know the least priced combination of objects without iterating over the whole List of combination, which I can't seem to find feasible.

Could someone suggest any changes that let the *maxLength* be higher(much higher ideally), without hindering the performance. Any help is much appreciated. Please let me know if I am not clear.

```
    private static int leastPrice = int.MaxValue;

    private IEnumerable<IEnumerable<OBJECT>> CombinationOfObjects(IEnumerable<OBJECT> objects, int length)
    {
        if (length == 1)
            return objects.Select(t => new OBJECT[] { t });

        return CombinationOfObjects(objects, length - 1).SelectMany(t => objects, (t1, t2) => t1.Concat(new OBJECT[] { t2 }));
    }

    //Gets the least priced Valid combination out of all possible
    public IEnumerable<OBJECT> GetValidCombination(IEnumerable<OBJECT> list, int maxLength, int[] matArray)
    {
        IEnumerable<IEnumerable<OBJECT>> tempList = null;

        List<IEnumerable<OBJECT>> validList = new List<IEnumerable<OBJECT>>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= maxLength; i++)
        {
            tempList = CombinationOfObjects(list, i);

            tempList = from alist in tempList
                       orderby alist.Sum(x => x.Price)
                       select alist;

            foreach (var lst in tempList)
            {
                //This check will not be required if the least priced value is returned as soon as found
                int price = lst.Sum(c => c.Price);
                if (price < leastPrice)
                {
                    if (CheckMaterialSum(lst, matArray))
                    {
                        validList.Add(lst);
                        leastPrice = price;
                        break;
                        //return lst;
                        //returning lst as soon as valid combo is found is fastest
                        //Con being it also returns the least priced least item containing combo
                        //i.e. even if a 4 item combo is cheaper than the 2 item combo satisfying the need,
                        //it'll never even check for the 4 item combo

                    }
                }
            }
        }

        //This whole thing would go too if lst was returned earlier
        foreach (IEnumerable<OBJECT> combination in validList)
        {
            int priceTotal = combination.Sum(combo => combo.Price);
            if (priceTotal == leastPrice)
            {
                return combination;
            }
        }

        return new List<OBJECT>();
    }

     //Checks if the given combination satisfies the requirement 
    private bool CheckMaterialSum(IEnumerable<OBJECT> combination, int[] matArray)
    {
        int[] sumMatProp = new int[matArray.Count()];

        for (int i = 0; i < matArray.Count(); i++)
        {
            sumMatProp[i] = combination.Sum(combo => combo.Numbers[i]);
        }

        bool isCombinationValid = matArray.Zip(sumMatProp, (requirement, c) => c >= requirement).All(comboValid => comboValid);

        return isCombinationValid;
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<OBJECT> testList = new List<OBJECT>();

        OBJECT object1 = new OBJECT();
        object1.Name = "object1";
        object1.Price = 2000;
        object1.Numbers = new int[] { 2, 3, 4 };
        testList.Add(object1);

        OBJECT object2 = new OBJECT();
        object2.Name = "object2";
        object2.Price = 1900;
        object2.Numbers = new int[] { 3, 2, 4 };
        testList.Add(object1);

        OBJECT object3 = new OBJECT();
        object3.Name = "object3";
        object3.Price = 1600;
        object3.Numbers = new int[] { 4, 3, 2 };
        testList.Add(object1);

        int requiredNumbers = new int[]{10,10,10};
        int maxLength = 9;//This is the max length possible, OutOf Mememory exception after this
        IEnumerable<OBJECT> resultCombination = GetValidCombination(testList, maxLength, requiredNumbers);

    }
```

**EDIT**

**Requirement:**

I have a number of objects having several properties, namely, *Price*, *Name* , and *Materials*. Now, I need to find such a combination of these objects that the sum of all materials in a combination satisfies the user input qty of materials. Also, the combination needs to be of least price possible. 
There is a constraint of *maxLength* and it sets the maximum total number of objects that can be in a combination, i.e. for a *maxLength* = 8, the combination may contain anywhere from 1 to 8 objects.

**Approaches tried:**

1.

> -I find all combinations of objects possible (valid + invalid)
>
> -Iterate over them to find the least priced combination. This goes out of memory while iterating.

  2.

> -I find all combinations possible (valid + invalid)
>
> -Apply a validity check (i.e if it fulfills the user requirement)
>
> -Add only valid combinations in a List of List
>
> -Iterate over this valid List of lists to find the cheapest list and return that. Also goes out of memory

3.

> -I find combinations in increasing order of objects (i.e. first all combinations having 1 object, then 2 then so on...)
>
> -Sort the combinations according to price
>
> -Apply validity check and return the first valid combination
>
> -Now this works fine performance wise, but does not always return the cheapest possible combination.

If I could somehow get the optimal solution without iterating over the whole list , that would solve it. But, all of the things that I've tried either have to iterate over all combinations or simply do not result in the optimal solution.

Any help regarding even some other approach that I can't seem to think of is most welcome.

Comment: It might be a case of the Mondays, but I find your code quite hard to follow. Is it doing some sort of breadth-first search? Can you explain the algorithm in words, and perhaps trim down the code to a [mcve]?

Comment: Looks like you're solving a knapsack problem in an overly naive way. Checking all possible combinations is not typically an acceptable solution for all but very small inputs. Even if you get around the memory problems, running times would quickly become unacceptable.

Comment: I think you need to give more info on what the code is suppose to do. What do you mean  requiredNumbers criteria. For micro optimization IEnumerable is not the way to go there is a lot of overhead. But you algorithm is just bad performance wise regardless. In many cases with NP-complete problems you don't need the find optimal solutions just a good enough but this depends on the scenario you have.

Comment: I have added a simple explanation of what the problem is and what I have tried so far, maybe it helps

Comment: @JeroenMostert The problem resembles a knapsack problem, but the catch is that each object has multiple materials with varying number (multiple weights) for the same price, thus I can't determine a ratio that would be optimal

Comment: Then it looks more like a linear programming problem, after writing the objects out as constraints.